# In what case(s) does the Euler-Maclaurin summation method yield the exact evaluation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, euler-maclaurin

So I've been fiddling around with the Euler-Maclaurin summation [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) a bit. Here's the formula: $$\sum_{i=m}^{n} f(i) = \int_{m}^{n} f(x) dx + \frac{f(n)+f(m)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2 \rfloor} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}(f^{(2k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(m)) + R_{p} .$$

Usually, it yields an approximation, because the third term (the sum involving the Bernoulli numbers) and the remainder term cannot be evaluated exactly.

I wonder whether there are cases in which these terms *can* be evaluated, and if so, if some systematic study has been done on the circumstances under which such an evaluation is possible.

Comment: If the higher derivatives are eventually all zero at the endpoints, the formula becomes exact. Such an example is Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: I would definitely check out the book [Summability Calculus](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319746470). I believe there is a preprint up on the arXiv.